# can't make addition in NSMutableArray obectatindex

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
for(int i=0; i<[arrMaintenanceDetail count]; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"maintenanceCategory"] count]; j++){

        if([[arrMaintenanceDetail objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"maintenanceCategory"]objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]]){

            [arrTotalValues objectAtIndex:i] += [arrTotalValues insertObject:[[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"cost"] objectAtIndex:j] integerValue] atIndex:i];

        }
    }

}
```

I want to add *(make addition of integer values)* value from 
`[[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"cost"] objectAtIndex:j] integerValue];`
Whenever loop changes its value.

I want new value from `objectAtIndex:j` to be added to its previous value and store it for future use.

I will have 4 objects in **arrTotalValues** (`NSMutableArray`).

So what should I do ??

Comment: Give more code with sample data you keep in this array. Do you keep NSNumbers inside, or NSString ?

Comment: I have this portion of code only, but what else do you need please explain.
I want to store float type of values to each object of mutablearray.

Comment: Dump the data you are working with.

Comment: What is the purpose of dumping data ?? What should I do by making copy of an array ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep integers in NSMutableArray. Use NSNumber to keep integer values in your NSMutableArray as objects.

You didn't provide enough information to give you 100% working code, but try something like that:

```
NSMutableArray* arrTotalValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=0; i<[arrMaintenanceDetail count]; i++)
{
    NSNumber* totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    for(int j=0; j<[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"maintenanceCategory"] count]; j++)
    {
        if([[[arrMaintenanceDetail objectAtIndex:i] stringValue] isEqualToString:[[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"maintenanceCategory"] objectAtIndex:i] stringValue]])
        {
            int newTotalValue = [totalValue intValue] + [[[arrMaintenanceCategory valueForKey:@"cost"] objectAtIndex:j] integerValue];
            totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newTotalValue];
        }
    }

    [arrTotalValues addObject:totalValue];
}
```

Comment: Can I store float values into it ??

Comment: YES, NSNumber is used for keeping all basic number types.